# I want to print tensor value by lldb

Tags: c++, tensorflow, lldb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW8Uz.jpg)

I want to print Buffer member variable in buf_， in other words, 
I want to `p *(tensorflow::Buffer*)buf_` to print member variables in class Buffer .

Codes in tensorflow, 1.10.1 .

Class relations : class TensorBuffer is base class in tensor.h, Buffer is a template and derived class in tensor.cc

The following is the output of lldb：

```
frame #0: 0x0000000175abffc0
```

libtensorflow_framework.so`tensorflow::Tensor::Tensor(this=0x000070000cadd308, a=0x00007fd91ea61500, type=DT_STRING, shape=0x000070000cadd2f0) at tensor.cc:726:3

```
     723  CHECK_NOTNULL(a);

     724  if (shape_.num_elements() > 0 || a->ShouldAllocateEmptyTensors()) {

     725    CASES(type, buf_ = new Buffer<T>(a, shape.num_elements()));

->   726  }


(lldb) p buf_

(tensorflow::TensorBuffer *) $17 = 0x00007fd91e927c40

(lldb) p *(Buffer<std::__1::string>*)buf_

error: use of undeclared identifier 'Buffer'

error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction

error: expected expression

(lldb) p *(tensorflow::Buffer<std::__1::string>*)buf_

error: no member named 'Buffer' in namespace 'tensorflow'

error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction

error: expected expression
```

line 725 decode :

```
switch(type)

case DataTypeToEnum<string>::value :

{

    typedef string T;

    buf_ = new Buffer<T>(a, shape.num_elements(), allocation_attr);

}
```

Comment: I reinstall lldb 9.0.0,but has same question .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a problem with reconstructing template types from the debug info.  The DWARF debug info format doesn't have an abstract representation for a template.  It only records instantiated templates (i.e. there is no abstract `std::vector<T>` but only `std::vector<int>`, `vector<std::string>`, etc.

Making up a base "std::string" type, for instance, that clang requires for casting, out of a bunch of specific instantiations, is not something lldb has been taught to do yet, and turns out to be fairly tricky.

You can work around this on an ad hoc basis by introducing typedef's for the types you want to print, e.g.:

```
(lldb) source list -l 1
   1    #include <vector>
   2    #include <string>
   3    #include <stdio.h>
   4    
   5    int
   6    main()
   7    {
   8      using VecType = std::vector<std::string>;
   9      std::vector<std::string> my_vec = {"string", "other string"};
   10     void *hidden = (void *) &my_vec;
(lldb) 
   11     VecType *revealed = (VecType *) hidden;
   12     return 0;
   13   }
   14   
   15     
(lldb) expr *(std::vector<std::string> *) hidden
error: no member named 'vector' in namespace 'std'
error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
error: expected expression
(lldb) expr *(VecType *) hidden
(VecType) $0 = size=2 {
  [0] = "string"
  [1] = "other string"
```

}

This is obviously not a great solution, since you have to have introduced these typedef's into your code in order to use them in the debugger.  Further, you need to not just define them, but also use them, or the compiler will not emit them into the debug info.  So if I left out line 11 above, I would have gotten:

```
(lldb) expr *(VecType *) hidden
error: use of undeclared identifier 'VecType'
```

Comment: I try to find `using xxx = Buffer<string>`, but not find related codes.

Answer (score 0):

we can use tensor's data() function to solve this question .

for example `p (std::__1::string *)(tensor->buf_->data())`
and why we can use data() function in lldb ?